# Javascript tab content only flickers not showing appropriately when tab link clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create tabs like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs), but when i click the tab link, the tab content only flickers, not showing completely. I do not know why this happens, i already follow exactly like in the site but it does not work. What did i actually do wrong and  how to fix this? Please someone help me, i need this for my school assignment

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Pertemuan 1</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 :root{
  --warnaijo : #9fe0ac;
 }
 .full{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--warnaijo);
 }
 div{
  border-style: dotted;
 }
 .nav ul li{
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .nav ul{
  padding: 0;
 }
 .nav{
  width: 30%;
  background-color: var(--warnaijo);
  margin-right: 10px;
 }
 .full p, .nav p{
  margin-left: 10px;
 }
 a{
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 /* Style the tab content */
 .tabcontent {
   display: none;
 }
</style>
<body>
 <div class="full">
  <p>pertemuan 1 -- SISTEM PAKAR</p>
 </div><br>
 <span style="display: flex;">
  <div class="nav">
  <p>navigasi</p>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">profil</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">galeri</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">jadwal kuliah</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 140px; padding-left: 10px;width: 100%;">
   <div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="border-style: none;">
     <h3>London</h3>
     <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent" style="border-style: none;">
     <h3>Paris</h3>
     <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent" style="border-style: none;">
     <h3>Tokyo</h3>
     <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </span><br><br>
 <div class="full">
  <p style="text-align: center;">@2019</p>
 </div>


<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `a` tag and instead of that please use buttons. This problem will be solved. Due to `a` tag with href pointed to #, it will refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the `href` on `a` attribute and it solves the problem

Comment: Why use `a` if you dont want the behaviour of `a`? Can as good put the click event on `li`.

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot about that, thanks for reminding me